# C# Form not inserting values into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, insert, sqlconnection

I have a simple create a new user form which takes values from two text boxes, username and password. The button2 click event should take these values and insert them into the Users table in the database. However, when I run my code the message box appears to say the data has been added, I cannot see the data in the database using VS2010.

See screen shot for the database connection in VS. I have also created a datasource of the database in VS.

Any Ideas?

Much appreciated.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        string sqlquery;
        string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DebenhamsProjectOffice V.01\DebenhamsProjectOffice V.01\DebenhamsProjectOfficeDatabase.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to Database");
        }

        sqlquery = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('" + txtUsername.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "')";
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("User Added");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        txtUsername.Text = "";
        txtPassword.Text = "";
        cn.Close();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying a code fix. Some elements are crucial, some are just elegant.
Try it, it might work., or could point to where the error is:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        string sqlquery;

        //Put away the apostrophes and used twice double quotations for
        //the full path of the database file:
        string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DebenhamsProjectOffice V.01\DebenhamsProjectOffice V.01\DebenhamsProjectOfficeDatabase.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);

        /* Better to let the program fail than think it's open and moving on
        removed try, catch*/
        cn.Open();


        //Why using your TextBoxes values if you already created strings?
        //changed

        //you should also be careful users can't type something like "') in the      
        //textboxes or they may cause a SQL injection

        sqlquery = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('" + username + "','" + password + "')";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cn);
            /* unnecessary since you already built a query command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);
            command.Parameters.Clear();   */

            //Missing!!
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("User Added");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        //Elegance
        txtUsername.Clear();
        txtPassword.Clear();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for taking the time to fix this. It now works!

Answer (score 5):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `DebenhamsProjectOfficeDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DebenhamsProjectOfficeDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also: you should **always** use parametrized queries and not concatenate together your SQL statements (**especially** not when user input is included!) to (a) avoid any danger of SQL injection attacks, and to (b) improve performance!

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice I will try this, apologies for the naivety I am a novice c# programmer. Much appreciated.

Comment: `catch (Exception)` is another flawed approach.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call [Command.ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) in order to take the effect of `insert` statement.

```
try
{
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cn);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      command.Parameters.Clear();
      MessageBox.Show("User Added");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```