# Insert command works without errors in C# but data is not inserted to the MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to insert data into Microsoft SQL Server DB using C# and the insert command works well and I get no errors or exceptions. But when I check my database in SQL Server there is no effect on the table and the records are not inserted into the table. This is the code that I try:

```
try
{
   SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection();
   con1.ConnectionString = "Server = (local); Database = My_DataBase; Integrated Security = true";
   con1.Open();
   SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand();
   cm1.Connection = con1;
   cm1.CommandText = "insert into Users values('" + update.Message.Chat.Id.ToString() + "','" + update.Message.Chat.FirstName + "','" + update.Message.Chat.LastName + "','@" + update.Message.Chat.Username + "','" + req1.Status + "')";
   con1.Close();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    continue;
}
```

I've seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361554/inserting-data-into-sql-server-does-not-work-but-there-is-no-error-message-to-sh) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854300/c-sharp-form-not-inserting-values-into-sql-server-database), but the answers did not fix my problem.

Also when I insert data to the DB manually and run select command like mentioned below, I get the correct answer but for the insert command I do not.

```
SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection();
con2.ConnectionString = "Server = (local); Database = My_DataBase; Integrated Security = true";
con2.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Users where ChatID='" + update.Message.Chat.Id.ToString() + "'", con2);
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
da1.Fill(ds1);
con1.Close();
```

Please help me fix this issue.

By the way I know that this kind of insertion is not safe and I'l like to let you know that this is just a demo and I will make it secure against ***sql injection.***

Comment: I don't have idea on .net/c# but does it auto commit the data?

Comment: You even have the same problem as the second question you linked. You don't have execute anywhere...

Comment: Since you say you are going to change this query to prevent sql injection why put much effort into this? You first need to fix the query before you test it. And get rid of that basically empty catch. It will write to the console before you can even see it and then it just closes.

Comment: @Habib I'm trying this in a Console Application and I've put my code in try-catch to get the possible exceptions but I don't and the code in the catch block works well.

Comment: @JamesZ The main scheme will not change, And the console will not close because the program is a telegram bot therefore the console keeps on being open until the bot stops. I've just mentioned a piece of code.

Comment: just curious, but what is the continue statement in your catch doing there ?

Comment: @GuidoG I just copied from my main code, That's because I'm trying to connect to the database in a while loop with a group of if and else-if blocks where in the case of entering to one if or else-if block the app most go to the beginning of the while loop after running the command in that if - else-if block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not executing your command anywhere. 
You need:

```
cm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In your code, you are creating a `SqlCommand` object, then you associate a `SqlConnection` to it, but in no where you are actually executing the command. Your code should look like:

```
   SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection();
   con1.ConnectionString = "Server = (local); Database = My_DataBase; Integrated Security = true";
   con1.Open();
   SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand();
   cm1.Connection = con1;
   cm1.CommandText = "insert into Users values('" + update.Message.Chat.Id.ToString() + "','" + update.Message.Chat.FirstName + "','" + update.Message.Chat.LastName + "','@" + update.Message.Chat.Username + "','" + req1.Status + "'";
   cm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con1.Close();
```

Apart from SQL Injection vulnerability, you should consider enclosing your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` object in `using` statement, that will ensure proper disposal of un-managed resources.

Comment: Thanks Habib, You were right I had forgotten to execute my command. Please explain more about enclosing my command and connection.

Comment: @parisa, this is a good  read https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C