# Unable to insert data in database - No exception thrown

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to insert data to `[AdventureWorks2017].[HumanResources].[Employee]` using a stored procedure. I've tested the stored procedure and it works fine for the values that I'm providing using the C# code.

When I try to do the same with slightly different values (same format), the code throws no exception or errors, but the values are not reflected in the database. I've tried to debug, all variables have values to be inserted and connection to database is open too.

```
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(1962, 07, 21);
    DateTime hireDate = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
    employee.RegisterEmployee("EM", 0, "Mr.", "Rakesh", "null", "Tripathi", "null", 0, "null", "null", "667567", "adventure-works\rakesh", "null", "Vice President of Engineering", birthDate, 'M', 'M', hireDate, 1, 100, 20, 1);
}

public int RegisterEmployee(string personType, int nameStyle, string title, string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, string suffix,
    int emailPromotion, string additionalContactInfo, string demographics, string nationalIdNumber, string loginId, string organizationNode, string jobtitle,
    DateTime dateOfBirth, char maritalStatus, char gender, DateTime hireDate, int salaried, int vacationHours, int sickLeaveHours, int currentFlag )
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand;

    try 
    {
        this.ConnectToDatabase();
        this.sqlConnection.Open();

        string commandText = "usp_RegisterNewEmployee";
        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, this.sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonType", personType);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameStyle", nameStyle);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstName);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", jobtitle);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", dateOfBirth);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailPromotion", emailPromotion);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus",maritalStatus);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HireDate", hireDate);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalariedFlag", salaried);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VacationHours", vacationHours);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SickLeaveHours", sickLeaveHours);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentFlag",currentFlag);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalIdNumber", nationalIdNumber);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", loginId);

        if (middleName == "null")
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", DBNull.Value);
        else
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", middleName);

        if (suffix == "null")
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Suffix", DBNull.Value);
        else
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Suffix", suffix);

        if (additionalContactInfo == "null")
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdditionalContactInfo", DBNull.Value);
        else
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdditionalContactInfo", additionalContactInfo);

        if (demographics == "null")
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Demographics", DBNull.Value);
        else
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Demographics", demographics);

        if (organizationNode == "null")
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganizationNode", DBNull.Value);
        else
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganizationNode", organizationNode);

        SqlParameter BusinessEntityIdOutput = new SqlParameter("@BusinessEntityIdOutput", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
        BusinessEntityIdOutput.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(BusinessEntityIdOutput);

        SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
        returnValue.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

        int result = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("total rows affected:", result);
        int businessEntityId = Convert.ToInt32(BusinessEntityIdOutput.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Business entity id: " + businessEntityId);
    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some error occurred...");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to find the solution from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582218/insert-command-works-without-errors-in-c-sharp-but-data-is-not-inserted-to-the-m), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854300/c-sharp-form-not-inserting-values-into-sql-server-database) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361554/inserting-data-into-sql-server-does-not-work-but-there-is-no-error-message-to-sh) but these don't apply in my case.

Below is the stored procedure I'm using to insert the values.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RegisterNewEmployee]
(
    /*Parameters required for person*/
    @PersonType         [nchar](2),
    @NameStyle          [dbo].[NameStyle] = 0,
    @Title              [nvarchar](8),
    @FirstName          [dbo].[Name],
    @MiddleName         [dbo].[Name],
    @LastName           [dbo].[Name],
    @Suffix             [nvarchar](10),
    @EmailPromotion     [int],
    @AdditionalContactInfo [xml] = NULL,
    @Demographics       [xml] = NULL,

    /*Parameters required for Employee*/
    @NationalIdNumber   [nvarchar](15),
    @LoginID            [nvarchar](256),
    @OrganizationNode   [hierarchyid],
    @JobTitle           [nvarchar](50),
    @BirthDate          [date],
    @MaritalStatus      [nchar],
    @Gender             [nchar],
    @HireDate           [date],
    @SalariedFlag       [dbo].[Flag],
    @VacationHours      [smallint], 
    @SickLeaveHours     [smallint],
    @CurrentFlag        [dbo].[Flag],
    @BusinessEntityIdOutput INT OUT
)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
                DECLARE @BusinessEntityID INT
        /* Enter new business entity id column in Person.BusinessEntity table */
                INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2017].[Person].[BusinessEntity] 
VALUES (NEWID(), GETDATE());
                SELECT @BusinessEntityID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                SET @BusinessEntityIdOutput = @BusinessEntityID;

            /* Register the same person in Person.Person table */
              INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2017].[Person].[Person]
              (
                [BusinessEntityID], 
                [PersonType],
                [NameStyle], 
                [Title], 
                [FirstName],
                [MiddleName], 
                [LastName], 
                [Suffix], 
                [EmailPromotion], 
                [AdditionalContactInfo],
                [Demographics], 
                [rowguid], 
                [ModifiedDate]
                ) VALUES 
                (
                    @BusinessEntityID,
                    @PersonType,
                    @NameStyle, 
                    @Title,
                    @FirstName,
                    @MiddleName,
                    @LastName,
                    @Suffix,
                    @EmailPromotion,
                    @AdditionalContactInfo, 
                    @Demographics,
                    NEWID(),
                    GETDATE()
                )

            /* Input the new row in the HumanResources.Employees table */
            INSERT INTO [HumanResources].[Employee]
            (
                [BusinessEntityID],
                [NationalIDNumber],
                [LoginID],
                [OrganizationNode],
                [JobTitle],
                [BirthDate],
                [MaritalStatus],
                [Gender],
                [HireDate],
                [SalariedFlag],
                [VacationHours],
                [SickLeaveHours],
                [CurrentFlag],
                [rowguid],
                [ModifiedDate]
            )
            VALUES
           (
                @BusinessEntityID,
                @NationalIdNumber,
                @LoginID, 
                @OrganizationNode,
                @JobTitle,
                @BirthDate,
                @MaritalStatus,
                @Gender,
                @HireDate,
                @SalariedFlag,
                @VacationHours,
                @SickLeaveHours,
                @CurrentFlag,
                NEWID(),
                GETDATE()
            )
        COMMIT
        --RETURN @BusinessEntityIdOutput
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK;
        RETURN -99
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: So which values work and which values don't work?

Comment: I highly recommend replacing all your `AddWithValue` with `Add` and building the SqlParameter yourself with the correct datatype. There are many [problems](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) when using `AddWithValue`.

Comment: We'll probably need to see your SP code as well.

Comment: Some general suggestions: 1. Change `RegisterEmployee` to accept a class (model) and have properties where you now have multiple method arguments. Example: `public class EmployeeModel { public string Title {get; set; } }`. 2. Do not use `"null"` instead of `null', that is also asking for problems. 3. Use enumerations or other constraints for things like personType where the values are likely limited to a specific subset. Finally do not use "AddWithValue", use Add instead and include the data type and length if applicable.

Comment: What does stored procedure look like?  Is it using Insert or Update?  If you have a primary key Update will work, but Insert will do nothing if primary key already exists (you will not get an error).

Comment: Need to see your SP.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but, your result will always be 0.

Comment: What is the value of result after the call?  Does your stored proc have a return statement and if so is it returning 0 as if it was successful?  As mentioned  above you are not getting a rowcount from the proc.  If you want one you'll need to add an output parameter and put the value of @@ROWCOUNT in it in the body of your stored proc, directly after the  DML command.

Comment: @Dale I'll go through the link you provided for AddWithValues(). I was just reading a ADO.NET article and trying to implement things they wrote, but on a different database.

Comment: @Igor I just started to learn developing data access layer in ADO.NET. The model classes chapter is in different module. Once i get comfortable with them, i'll try to incorporate that into this code as well.

Comment: @jdweng The primary key is [BusinessEntityId]. I'm trying the insert statements in SP. The PK is getting incremented at each debug iteration i perform. So, i think the duplicate PK insertion is not the issue here

Comment: Did you test stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio with same data you are trying to store?  Check if you are getting to the catch.  The error messages in SSMS are much better than c# and usually will tell exactly what is wrong.  I always recommend testing any query in SSMS before trying in c# especially complicated queries.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the stored procedure is updating 2 tables.

I moved the try...catch to the UI code where you communicate with the user.

Connections need to be not only closed but disposed to release unmanaged objects. `using` blocks handle this even if there is an error.
Commands also need to be disposed.

The code below demonstrates how to use the `.Add` method for parameters. `Bit` fields in Sql Server map to `Boolean` in .net. `@AdditionalContactInfo` and `@Demographics` are `XML` types but since they are null in your code. I will not worry about it. You don't appear to use the 2 out parameters and since they do not require a value I am thinking we don't need to include them. They are probably used internally by the stored procedure.

Unless the stored procedure is providing a value for `rowguid` (it probably is) you will have to provide it. Also `ModifiedDate` is probably handled in the stored procedure. Both of these fields are not null in the Employee table.

```
    private void OPCode()
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(1962, 07, 21);
        DateTime hireDate = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
        try
        { 
        int retval = employee.RegisterEmployee("EM", 0, "Mr.", "Rakesh", "null", "Tripathi", "null", 0, "null", "null", "667567", "adventure-works\rakesh", "null", "Vice President of Engineering", birthDate, 'M', 'M', hireDate, 1, 100, 20, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
     }

public class Employee
{

    private string ConStr = "Your connection string";

    public int RegisterEmployee(string personType, int nameStyle, string title, string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, string suffix,
        int emailPromotion, string additionalContactInfo, string demographics, string nationalIdNumber, string loginId, string organizationNode, string jobtitle,
        DateTime dateOfBirth, char maritalStatus, char gender, DateTime hireDate, int salaried, int vacationHours, int sickLeaveHours, int currentFlag)
        {
            int result;
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
             using (SqlCommand  cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_RegisterNewEmployee", cn))
              {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PersonType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2).Value = personType;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NameStyle", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToBoolean(nameStyle);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8).Value = title;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = firstName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value = lastName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@JobTitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value = jobtitle;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BirthDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateOfBirth;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailPromotion", SqlDbType.Int).Value = emailPromotion;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MaritalStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar,1).Value = maritalStatus;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar,1).Value = gender;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@HireDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = hireDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SalariedFlag", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToBoolean(salaried);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@VacationHours", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = vacationHours;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SickLeaveHours", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = sickLeaveHours;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurrentFlag", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToBoolean(currentFlag);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NationalIdNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar,15).Value = nationalIdNumber;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LoginID", SqlDbType.NVarChar,256).Value = loginId;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Suffix", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdditionalContactInfo", SqlDbType.Xml);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Demographics", SqlDbType.Xml);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrganizationNode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BusinessEntityIdOutput", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["@BusinessEntityIdOutput"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    

               if (middleName == "null")
                    cmd.Parameters["@MiddleName"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                else
                    cmd.Parameters["@MiddleName"].Value = middleName;

                if (suffix == "null")
                    cmd.Parameters["@Suffix"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                else
                    cmd.Parameters["@Suffix"].Value = suffix;

                if (additionalContactInfo == "null")
                    cmd.Parameters["@AdditionalContactInfo"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                else
                   cmd.Parameters["@AdditionalContactInfo"].Value = additionalContactInfo;

                if (demographics == "null")
                    cmd.Parameters["@Demographics"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                else
                    cmd.Parameters["@Demographics"].Value = demographics;

                if (organizationNode == "null")
                    cmd.Parameters["@OrganizationNode"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                else
                    cmd.Parameters["@OrganizationNode"].Value = organizationNode;

                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
                return result;
        }
}
```